# Converting a A0 potrait size poster to A1 Potrait Size Poster

Tags: posters, beamerposter

Could anyone please help me to convert [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/iit-jodhpur-poster-template/nsptnywpnjfb) poster to ''A1-Potrait''? All I want is an A1-size poster with the same style as the poster.

```
 \documentclass[final]{beamer}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}  
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage[english]{babel} 
    \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.0{beamerposter}
    \usetheme{gemini}
    \usecolortheme{nott}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
    \usepackage{anyfontsize}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[skip=2pt,font=normalsize]{subcaption}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
    \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width = 10cm, draw=black, fill=white]
    \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width = 6cm, draw=black, fill=white, text width = 10cm]
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [ultra thick,->,>=stealth]
    \newlength{\sepwidth}
    \newlength{\colwidth}
    \setlength{\sepwidth}{0.025\paperwidth}
    \setlength{\colwidth}{0.45\paperwidth}
    \newcommand{\separatorcolumn}{\begin{column}{\sepwidth}\end{column}}
    
    \title{Poster Title  Poster Title Poster Title Poster Title Poster Title Poster Title Poster Title Poster Title}
    \title{Poster Title for Condensed Matter Physics / High Energy Physics / Computational Physics}
    
    \author{First Author \inst{1} \and Corresponding Author \inst{1}}
    \institute[shortinst]{\inst{1} Indian Institute of Technology Jodhpur 
    }
    
    \footercontent{
    \href{https://www.lipsum.com}{\textbf{https://www.lipsum.com}} \hfill
    \textbf{International Conference on Physics} \hfill
    \href{mailto:your.email@provider.com}{\textbf{Email Id}}}
    
    \logoleft{\includegraphics[height=8cm]{IITJ_logo.png}}
    
    \usepackage{pgf}
   \begin{document}
\fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{columns}[t]
\separatorcolumn

\begin{column}{\colwidth}

\begin{block}{Abstract}
\blindtext
\end{block}
  
\begin{exampleblock}{Research objectives}
\blindenumerate[3]
\end{exampleblock}
\end{document}
```

**Edit [cfr]:** the following is a more minimal, working version of the code above which does not leave environments unfinished, include fatal syntax errors or rely on non-standard files. It may or may not reflect the OP's intent. If not, the OP can hopefully edit it so it does while keeping it minimal.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a1,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}
\newlength{\sepwidth}
\newlength{\colwidth}
\setlength{\sepwidth}{0.025\paperwidth}
\setlength{\colwidth}{0.45\paperwidth}
\newcommand{\separatorcolumn}{\begin{column}{\sepwidth}\end{column}}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont

\begin{frame}[t]
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \separatorcolumn
    
    \begin{column}{\colwidth}
      
      \begin{block}{Abstract}
        \blindtext
      \end{block}
      
      \begin{exampleblock}{Research objectives}
        \blindenumerate[3]
      \end{exampleblock}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hyperlinks can and do decay over time, rendering your posting in its current form incomprehensible to future readers. Hence please post the actual code here, rather than just providing a hyperlink to some other site. Also, what kind of help are you hoping to get? E.g., do you want to shrink the contents linearly to make them fit on an A1 page? Or do you want to distribute the material across twice as many pages?  Please be specific.

Comment: Mico--Thanks--done that.

Comment: Thanks for adding some code, however it does not compile, there is no document body. Please also explain if you want to scale down your poster or if you want to keep the same font size. -> voting to leave closed until you clarify your question

Comment: Sam--is it ok now?

Comment: @Myshkin Your code still does not compile and you still have not told us if you want to scale down the A0 poster or keep the same font size

Comment: @Myshkin You should also look up how pinging in comments works.

Comment: I am not understanding--- I just wanted a1 size --keeping everything same

Comment: You can't keep everything. You can either keep the layout or you can keep the font size. Are you maybe looking for `\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a1,scale=1]{beamerposter}`? (Your code still does not compile)

Comment: If I make your example compilable, simply changing `a0` to `a1` does what you apparently want, as @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz says. Of course, this means the abstract takes a larger proportion of the poster. If you don't want that, you have to make it smaller e.g. by reducing the font size `\fontsize{18pt}{27pt}\selectfont`, for example. The columns etc. still take the same proportion of the width etc. if that's what you mean by 'layout'. But if you put a thing on a big sheet of paper and another identical one on a smaller sheet, obviously the one on the smaller sheet takes more of it ;).

Comment: @Myshkin I've edited your question with a proposed minimal document. You should edit this if it doesn't reflect your intent, but without breaking it or making it rely on non-standard files. Could you please try to include this kind of example in future questions so we're able to help you better? You've asked 41 questions, but my admittedly small sample didn't turn up one with a proper MWE :(.

Comment: @cfr: thanks for cleaning up the OP's code; I am not sure if it is intentional, but you left your variant (with `a0` changed to `a1`) in there, so your MWE already generates an `a1` sized document. :)

Comment: @WillieWong I realised afterwards. So not really intentional, but I guess I intentionally failed to do anything about it. Do you think I should change it? I was kind of assuming the example wouldn't really reflect everything the OP wants, so would have to be edited anyway and would mostly serve as an example of an MWE rather than any kind of response to the question.

Comment: Comments in regards to font size: (a) ISO sizes differs by factors of sqrt(2), so 24pt becomes approximately 17pt tall. (b) beamerposter loads type1cm, and you can have decimals in your `\fontsize`, so scaling down from the MWE you are looking at something like `\fontsize{17pt}{25.5pt}` (c) It is much, much better to just use the `scale` load option for the package, since it creates appropriate size-switching commands **and** auto-scales with changing paper size. You may consider using it with `setspace` to select appropriate `baselinestretch`.

Comment: But you probably shouldn't scale fonts down by root 2 because you shouldn't try to fit on A1 as much as you'd fit on A0. So just scaling everything down proportionately will result in a poor quality poster. So definitely the `scale` option @WillieWong mentioned. (In case it wasn't obviously `\fontsize{18pt}{27pt}\selectfont` was not a recommendation and is almost certainly not what you want. For one thing, you don't typically want `\baselineskip` to scale simply proportionately to font size.)

Comment: Dear all, I am so sorry if the question has created a mess/chaos--the thing is, I liked the template, but it was A0, so all I wanted was if I could use the same stylization and all but get an A1 size. But now, I think finding any other A1 template is best and forget this template. I don't want to make noise. Many Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd simply compile the file as is, in A0 format and create a small LaTeX file, say `reduceposter.pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=594mm,paperheight=841mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{bigposter}% use the proper file name

\end{document}
```

giving as argument to `\includepdf` the name of your PDF file containing the poster.

Please note that `anyfontsize` is obsolete and not needed anyway, because `lmodern` provides fully scalable fonts.

Comment: Thanks I will try and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks--it worked perfectly--just out of curiosity--how could I do it the other way? Meaning from A1 to A0. Many Thanks.

Comment: @Myshkin Just use the dimensions of A0 paper. Google for them.